# Hibernate don't trigger registred EventListeners's on Spring implicit @Transactional annotated methods commit

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have an java applciation that uses both Hibernate and Spring, and also Hibernate session's programmatical transaction control and Spring's @Transactional automatic commit

I need to handle onFlush hibernate event, so with hibernate session it works, but when Spring makes @Transactional annotated methods automatic commit it fails.

I register hibernate event listeners:

```
EventListenerRegistry registry = sessionFactoryImpl.getServiceRegistry().getService(EventListenerRegistry.class);
registry.appendListeners(EventType.SAVE, this);
registry.appendListeners(EventType.SAVE_UPDATE, this);
registry.appendListeners(EventType.MERGE, this);
```

and the I do something like

1. session.save(entity), event listeners work as expected;
2. when I call Spring repository.save(), it also works
3. But when Spring makes @Transactional annotated methods automatic commit without calling to repository.save(), I don't enter hibernate event listener.

Can anyone pls help how to deal with it?

Comment: Please code for a method that **@Transactional annotated methods automatic commit without calling to repository.save()**

Comment: looks like @Transaction public saveEntity() { Document doc = getById(); doc.setPaymentPurpose("purpose"); }

Comment: You still need to call `save()` methods of your repository classes yourself. All that `@Transactional` annotation is doing is executing `commit()` or `rollback()`. If you do not persist your objects manually Spring will not do that for you.